# How to stack random objects on a surface with a shape square Geometry Nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry, simulation-nodes

I have trouble to create geometry nodes that stack my rocks on a square shape.
I would like to create a maya temple so I had the idea to use geometry nodes to do it using  rocks.

[image]

Here is the result I would like to get, basically I had the idea to do it level by level.
In red this is what I would like to achieve with the geometry nodes, to just do the fisrt level of rock from this temple for example.
[image]
Thanks in advance for any help :D

---

**Edit:**

This is what I did currently, but it takes the entire collection, I don't know how to pick object separetly from the collection.

[image]

Here is the result:[image]

Comment: please show us some pics or sketches what you want to achieve, thx. You can copy/paste images into your question.

Comment: I edited my question :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you wanna start with this?

I used GN simulation nodes already (because with it you can change each instance per frame which is pretty helpful in this case):

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Super cool the new 3.5 simulation nodes ! Thanks Chris for sharing.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for your answer this is exactly what I needed !

Comment: Oups I talked too quickly, is there a way to randomize the cube ? I have 5 differents object I would like to randomize

Comment: of course. You could just put your cubes in a collection and link that collection instead of the cube in the instance on point node. Exactly as you did it in your question. And please - don't change/update now your questions with additional wishes you didn't wrote before. Just accept the answer (click on the checkmark left of my answer) if it helped you. If you have other/more specific question, please open a new question. You can open as many as you want. If you ask additional things in the comment - nobody can find these questions. And others want to learn from this as well. thx.

Comment: Okay sorry I'm new to this forum

Comment: I just edited my post